# User add Macro in Visual Studio does not work

Tags: c++, properties, visual-studio-2017, vcxproj

I want to add macro in my vcxproj file, or more precisely in user .props file, which is loaded from my vcxproj file.

I use this user macro for name of destination exe file (in vcxproj file):

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <TargetName>MajAcTest_$(MyVariable)_$(Platform)</TargetName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And in prop file I have definition of this macro:

```
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformToolset Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">v141</PlatformToolset>
    <PlatformToolset Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Rel_2018'">v140</PlatformToolset>
    <PlatformToolset Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Rel_2019'">v140</PlatformToolset>
    <PlatformToolset Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Rel_2019'">v140</PlatformToolset>
    <PlatformToolset Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Rel_2020'">v141</PlatformToolset>
    <PlatformToolset Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Rel_2021'">v142</PlatformToolset>
    <PlatformToolset Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Rel_2022'">v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

If I open project in Visual Studio (2017), in properties semms to be all rigth - name of file is, eg. "MajAcTest_Rel_2018_x64"

[image: see this picture of properties]

But if I build file, the name of file is without my variable (MajAcTest__x64)

Why? Please help.

Comment: I suggest that you could save the changes, ,restart VS, select clean and rebuild. Sometimes, vcxproj can't update immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I try it but still it's the same. Program instead MajAcTest_2020_x64.arx generate MajAcTest__x64.arx. $(MajuArxVersion) is 2020. In edit window of property TargetName it is displayed right

Answer (score 0):

After I test the program, I find that you could make the following changes:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <TargetName>MajAcTest_$(Configuration)_$(Platform)</TargetName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Also, you need to set the `Sloutions Configurations` as `Rel_2018`.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is also the way. But I want to have My variable $(MajuuArxVersion)....and for generate name use this, not $(configuration).

Comment: My understanding is that you are setting the Target Name based on the Configuration. Isn't it? I can't understand what `MyVariable` is.